# How to use a custom export font for a section of text in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export, fonts

I am writing in org-mode and exporting to pdf via LaTeX. I am quite new to Emacs and org-mode, and not familiar with LaTeX, so I am flailing about on the following:

I would like for a small section of my text to be exported in a custom font which resides in my ~/.font directory (.ttf and .otf versions available).

1. Can it be done?
2. What tags/statements/syntax are used within the document?
3. Do I need to alter the Emacs setup? (My Emacs version is 24.5.1.)

There is a related LaTeX question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/25251#25251), but it does not involve Emacs/org-mode. The answer mentioning XeLaTeX would seem to offer the simplest route, but I don't know how to integrate this with org-mode. I had a look at org-mode's [documentation about embedded LaTeX](http://orgmode.org/manual/Embedded-LaTeX.html) - it seems to focus on math expressions, and I remain unclear as to whether something like font changing is supported, and then how.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: You could have defined a LaTeX macro (the one given by `myfont` in the question you refer to). You'd use `#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand*{\myfont}...` in the beginning of the file, and later in the text you'd use `\myfont{text rendered using my font}`.

Comment: To use orgmode to produce a LaTeX document, while being new to Emacs, orgmode and LaTeX, is an approach which will almost surely fail. Organise your work with orgmode, read a book about LaTeX and start writing your document using LaTeX, using Emacs and AuCTeX. And even this is not easy, independently from your work.

Comment: @KeksDose, it would be helpful if you can document or substantiate your claim that orgmode and LaTex approach fails. You also haven't said what is easy or hard. Based on your other comments, clicking a reference to get settings is hard for you.

Comment: @EmacsUser Diplora informs us to be a newbie regarding Emacs, orgmode and LaTeX. Obviously such a person isn't a hard boiled nerd, but someone who has heard of Orgmode and now struggels to get the needed pieces of software. However bright and educated someone is, this is a challenge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That custom font has to be first installed to your LaTeX
configuration. Follow these [instructions](http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/latexfonts.php).

Then use the custom font in org-mode files as shown in the sample below.
In org-mode, you should use C-e l p (which is export to LaTeX as PDF 
file) to see the custom font printed. The full complement of LaTeX
font [directives shown here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts) can then be used with the custom font 
in your org-mode file.

```
**** Some org header

Some sample text in normal font followed by \customfont{text in
custom font} and then revert back to normal font.
```

Comment: This is not helpfull as long as you don't explain how and where to define a command and the syntax.

Comment: @KeksDose the instructions link shows the exact command. What part of that did you find unhelpful?

Comment: Sorry, but the "instructions" are a bad joke. Installing a new font in LaTeX is really difficult. Try on your own, I bet you never did.

Comment: @KeksDose, I can see how you think the inventor of TeX gives notes that one of his students at Stanford posts those instructions and you think it is a joke? Unbelievable.

Comment: @KeksDose and Emacs User: please be constructive.

Comment: @EmacsUser In stackexchange sites, it's good to copy over the information instead of just providing a link. Self contained answers are better.

Comment: Finally got around to attempting this - and it works! Thanks, Emacs User. A few notes: (1) in order to use more than one custom font, and use their proper names rather than 'custom', I followed the comment by 'James at 2 Sep 2012' on the instructions page; (2) using uppercase in the font name did not seem to work for that - not sure where the problem lies; (3) just to be precise, the export shortcut is C-c C-e l p. And a further question: what is the equivalent for exporting to HTML -- and if I want to send the html file to someone else, will I need to send the font files too?

Comment: Also, wvxvw's comment (under my question) was helpful to make the \newcommand line execute. (I didn't know about #+LATEX_HEADER)

Comment: @Malabarba, I have a inconvenient habit of not violating copyrights and copying without permissions. If I had enough time, I would have gotten the proper releases from the Stanford Office that handles such requests before pasting content from Stanford website to stackexchange. Hence the link only.